# LibGDX : Textfield input type

Tags: libgdx, input, scene2d

I want to change TextField input type . When I click on the textfield the android keyboard appears with all the symbols , but I want only numbers and dot (**.**) .

```
TextFieldStyle textFieldStyle = new TextFieldStyle(font_38, Color.valueOf("646b6c"), getDrawable(atlas.findRegion("textField_cursor")), getDrawable(atlas.findRegion("textField_selection")), getDrawable(atlas.findRegion("textField_bg")));
TextField textField = new TextField("", textFieldStyle);    
textField .setTextFieldFilter(new TextFieldFilter.DigitsOnlyFilter());
```

I have done in this way but here the only inputs are numbers and there is no dot . And when I click on the textfield again android keyboard appears with all the symbols , but I can type only numbers . There is a keyboard in android only with numbers , how to open it instead of all the symbols keyboard and type numbers and dot?

Answer (score 7):

I found out a solution to your other problem. To allow the typing of a dot you should create your own implementation of `TextFieldFilter` like this.

```
public class DigitFilter implements TextFieldFilter {

private char[] accepted;

public DigitFilter() {
    accepted = new char[]{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.'};
}

@Override
public boolean acceptChar(TextField textField, char c) {
    for (char a : accepted)
        if (a == c) return true;
    return false;
}}
```

This simple solution should work with any kind of input you may want to allow.